# prepopulating username field on Azure AD login

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

When using Azure AD for authentication, does anyone know if it's possible to send the username as a parameter in the request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee so that this field is populated already in the login prompt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. You can specify the `login_hint` parameter.

For example:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/authorize?login_hint=test.guy@company.com
```

Of course you need to include the other standard parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible but you can customize your Login page with your own html UI. Once you customize the page you may try to add some javascript block to add the username in the field. (When doing UI customizations we cannot control the username/password fields).